# evaluateJavascript function reducing the number of backslashes

Tags: javascript, android, escaping, mathjax

I am trying to load javasctipt in `WebView` dynamically by calling `evaluateJavaScript()` method for android versions after kitkat and using `loadUrl("javascript:"+javascript);` on versions below kitkat. Let me explain in more detail what I am trying to do with the help of code below.

```
 if(mProblemMathView!=null && count <=10){
//this code is run when the full html is being loaded for the first time
//there is no error in this part
                    htmlStringBuilder.append(htmlStringEnding);
                    mProblemMathView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlStringBuilder.toString(), null, null, null);
                }
                else{
      //this part of code is run when html has been loaded atleast once

                    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

                        Log.e("Hi",htmlStringBuilder.toString());
                        mProblemMathView.evaluateJavascript(getScript(htmlStringBuilder,count), null);
                    } else {
                        Log.e("Hi","Hello2");
                        mProblemMathView.loadUrl(getScript(htmlStringBuilder,count));
                    }
                }
```

Below is the function which modifies `htmlStringBuilder` and returns a `String`

```
  private String getScript(StringBuilder htmlStringBuilder,int count){
            String script="var functionOne= function () {console.log('start');var div = document.createElement('div');div.id='recall_'+"+count+";" +
                    "div.innerHTML=\""+htmlStringBuilder.toString()+"\";document.body.appendChild(div);"
                    + "var math = document.getElementById('recall_'+"+count+");\n" +
                    "MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub,math]);"+"console.log('end');} \n functionOne();"
                    ;
            Log.e("s",script);
            return script;
        }
```

When I am loading html with `htmlStringBuilder` for the first time everything is fine but when I am loading javascript with `evaluateJavascript` method or the `loadUrl` method the problem I am facing is that javascript is being loaded with one less `\` character. How I know this is because I am using mathjax which uses `\\(\\)` or '$$' to identify the mathematics part. Now `htmlStringBuilder` fully uses `\\(\\)` to show mathematics so what I did was I appended `$2x$` at the right place and maths was rendered correctly and also at some places "\frac" was changed to "rac". This shows javascript is being evaluated with one less '\' character.

What should I do so that javascript is loaded the same way as it is loaded for the first time ?

**More Info**: What I am seeing is if I am using `\\\\(\\\\)` only then is the maths being rendered instead it should have been rendered at `\\( \\)`.
So why is Javascript loading with one less `\` character eg. `\( \)`?

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to find out *why* `WebView` reduces the number of blackslashes too. Unfortunately haven't found an answer to that yet.

As for how to deal with this issue, I've found 2 solutions:

### 1. When you're passing your "string with possible backslashes" to your WebView, replace all blackslahes ('\') with 2 backslashes ('\\')

```
getScript(htmlStringBuilder,count).replace('\\', '\\\\')
```

*(It looks like I'm replacing 2 with 4, but that's because I'm escaping the backslash character for Java.)*

So this line means that for every backslash in my string, add one more. Since `evaluateJavascript` reduces the number of backslashes (in a combination backslashes) by 1, this will result in the string being the same as it was in Java.

However, I'm not sure if this approach can ruin strings in some situations where backslashes need to be in a certain format. In my use cases this has always worked, but I'm not sure if it's a good general solution

### 2. URL Encode your String before passing it to your WebView

As someone suggested in my question about *WHY* this happens ([Why does WebView.evaluateJavascript() remove escape characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50583609/why-does-webview-evaluatejavascript-remove-escape-characters#answer-50622148)) you could URLEncode your string before passing it to your WebView

```
URLEncoder.encode(getScript(htmlStringBuilder,count), "UTF-8")
```

This is probably the best general solution. The only problem with this approach is that you have to make changes in your Javascript as well to URLDecode the string, which might be annoying or impossible to do in some cases