# Why does WebView.evaluateJavascript() remove escape characters?

Tags: android, json, android-webview

I have a stringified JSON object that I want to pass into my WebView as a string. If my JSON string is a simple one-level JSON like this:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject;
object.put("key1", "val1");
object.put("key2", "val2");
String myValue = object.toString();
```

And I run `evaluateJavascript` like this:

```
webView.evaluateJavascript("console.log('" + myValue + "')", null)
```

Then the console log I get is this:

```
{"key1": "val1", "key2", "val2"}
```

Which is correct.

But if my JSON has a sub JSON inside it, then the stringified version of that JSON should have escaped quotes in it for that inner JSON. So if I did this:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
object.put("key1", "val1");
JSONObject innerObject = new JSONObject();
innerObject.put("key3","val3");
object.put("key2", innerObject);
String myValue = object.toString();
```

And run the same `evaluateJavascript` statement above, I get the following console log

```
{"key1":"val1", "key2": "{"key3": "val3"}"}
```

Which is not what I am expecting! I'm expecting an output like this:

```
{"key1":"val1", "key2": "{\"key3\": \"val3\"}"}
```

The quotes of the inner JSON are supposed to be escaped. If they are not escaped, then trying to run a `JSON.parse` on it will result in a parse error.

I even used a debugger to inspect the run time value of `myValue` just before it is passed into `evaluateJavascript` and it looks the way it's supposed to:

```
"{"key1":"val1", "key2": "{\"key3\": \"val3\"}"}"
```

So why does running `evaluateJavascript` mysteriously strip away those explicit escape symbols?

### NOTE:

The only way I could solve this was to run the following statement just before `evaluateJavascript`

```
myValue.replace("\\", "\\\\")
```

That is, replacing any escape characters (`\`) with 2 escape characters (`\\`). That way, the mysterious stripping will remove one escape character but leave the other one there which allows me to successfully `JSON.parse` it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use URLEncode to encode the contents while using javascript interface.

```
URLEncoder.encode(contents, "UTF-8");
```

And then for getting back the actual contents in js you can use

```
decodeURIComponent(contents.replace(/\+/g, '%20'));
```

Comment: That's a really good suggestion. Didn't think of that. Thank you. But unfortunately my question is more of "why" does it do that. It almost looks like a strange bug to me. I was curious to know if there's a good reason why it behaves this way